# How can I compile a .deb file for network-manager's git

Tags: network-manager, packaging, git

I need to install a version of network-manager that has the enhanced nmcli (allowing creation of new connections from cli only), and I wasn't able to find a PPA with a recent enough version. How can I compile a deb file from network-manager's git repository to deploy this onto multiple machines?

I need to create this to be installed on Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: For a fast an dirty solution use chekinstall.

Comment: @JavierRivera: I need something that will be maintainable over time, not something fast and dirty. I'm aware of checkinstall but I'm sure that someone has a real thing that just needs slight tweaking to use the git repo.

Comment: I don't have comprehensive answer, but you could try looking at "View source package recipes" from https://launchpad.net/network-manager, which I *think* describe how the official Ubuntu packages are built. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~network-manager/network-manager/ubuntu/files appears to contain the package files used to build the .deb.

Answer (score 0):

### There are great tutorials out there, for example [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/).

In short:

You create the structure with all files and folders the packages creates and some kind of configuration file (called control) where you define depencies, architectures, name, description...

After that you build the package with dpkg.

Comment: I'm familiar with the basic packaging process, but specifically I'd like one that uses git to update itself rather than just getting a tarball.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe git-buildpackage is what you are looking for :

http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.html

Here is one tutorial on how using it (using python git) : https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Git-buildpackage

Best regards,